# Limit items in shopping cart

Tags: commerce

Is there a way to limit users on my site to buy only 2 items from a list of products?
Am using Drupal 7 with Commerce module and Rules.
I added a new rule to when adding or removing and item from the shopping cart, it would check if the total quantity is bigger than 2, then it would remove the last element like this.

> **Event**
>   Before adding a product to the cart
>
> After adding a product to the cart
>
> **Conditions**
>
> Total product quantity comparison
>   Parameter: Order: [commerce_order], Operator: >, Quantity: 2
>
> **Actions**
>
> Remove an item from a list
>
> Selected list: commerce-order:commerce-line-items

and the item to remove is

> commerce-order:commerce-line-items:2

Sadly its not working, and I really need your help. 
thanks

Comment: The conversation at http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/673 may be useful to you, but you have more sophisticated requirements.

Comment: well, this is helpful but in my case cause I want the action to be removing an element from the cart.

Comment: stumbled on this, but if you are still looking for the rule(s) necessary to limit product quantities, you can see the post at <a href="http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/1053">http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/1053</a>

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem:
I had to check for certain conditions before adding an item to the cart (not after adding). And if the condition is not met the item should not be added.

The only way i could resolve this is by adding a **"Execute custom PHP code"** action with the code:

```
drupal_goto('any_path');
```

This doesn't look very correct but its the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be very robust solution :)
but it may came in handy