# How to make a rule for limiting one product per cart

Tags: rules, commerce

Can anyone help me?
I want to know how to make a rule for limiting one product per cart. I found rule for limiting qty only but not order item.

I found this with code [Drupal Commerce Shopping cart limit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53351/drupal-commerce-shopping-cart-limit?rq=1)
But I want to do it with rule ...

Answer (score 6):

Yes, to restrict to one product per order, add a rule:

- Event: before add product to cart,
- Action: remove all products from cart.

The effect is existing products are removed and only the latest selected product is added to the cart.