# How can I limit the allowed quantity in the cart to one item?

Tags: 8, commerce

I am using Drupal 8/Commerce 2. How do I limit the quantity in the cart to one item so that users can't order more than one item per order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drupal Commerce Shopping cart limit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53351/drupal-commerce-shopping-cart-limit)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 / Commerce have field "Default quantity to add to cart", so you can add default quantity for product is 1 and hide it from product page. After that user can't change quantity of products. Problem is solved!

Comment: this does NOT stop the user from adding another product with quantity 1 ... so ***problem NOT solved*** ...

Answer (score 0):

Views >> Cart form >> Remove field... 
(order_items: Order Item) Order item: Quantity text field (Quantity)

This was a editable quantity field.

You can now add (order_items: Order Item) Order item: Quantity (Quantity)
Which is a display only version of the quantity field.

For your Order item type >> manage display >> purchased entity >> rendered as cart.

The same item can still be added 1 at a time to the cart. To best solve solve this problem it would depend on your situation.

(1) Is your product a 'one off' unique item? then best solved by a stock strategy -or- (2) Is only one item of a certain sku allowed in a cart -or- (3) Must each sku in a cart be unique?